# IReport + Hibernate Datasource set specific NamingStrategy in cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport, hibernate-mapping, hibernate.cfg.xml

I'm using IReport 4.5.1 and HQL for querying database. So I define an `hibernate.cfg.xml`, put its root folder and required *.jar files to IReport's classpath. The problem arises when I  want to use my own Naming Strategy. It simply converts `someObject` into table name `SOME_OBJECT`. IReport could not trigger naming strategy so it searches for the table `someObject`. I've tried

```
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy
ejb.naming_strategy
namingStrategy
```

property names in cfg.xml but no luck. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks all.